# Combine 2 docker image in a single "service"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have recently started studying docker and was wondering about something: let's assume that we want to provide a customer with a service consisting of application + database.

From the "manual", what I would do is to use compose to build the architecture between the two services. But once the build is done, I get two separate images, right?

What I am wondering is, is there any way that the customer can do a simple
`docker run user/remoterepo:version`  and the two images (db, app) are pulled at the same time? It is otherwise inconvenient to have to pass the docker-compose.yml to the client.

I hope I have explained myself.

Thank you very much!

I would like to dock a service consisting of several services that talk to each other. With `docker run user/remoterepo:version` I would like both services to start at the same time without having to pass the docker-compose.yml file to the customer.

What I expect could be something like: 'group several separate containers in a single image'.

Comment: Note that the `docker-compose.yml` file is essentially just a set of `docker run` options in YAML format.  You'll probably need some non-default options – publishing ports, an actually-random database password, persistence for the database – and distributing the `docker-compose.yml` file might still be easier than writing out a very long `docker run` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't easily combine existing container images into one as you propose.

The convention is to distribute multiple images (somewhat analogous to micro-services with each performing a specific role) and then a mechanism such as Docker Compose that assembles these into a virtual network of interacting components.

One reason for this approach is that each image usually represents a single process and -- conventionally -- one container (from one image) represents a single process (rather than multiple processes).

The advantage of this mechanism is that you can e.g.:

1. Upgrade each component separately;
2. Connect multiple frontends to one backend database;
3. Don't need to support multiple process in a single container (see below); etc.

If you would like to distribute a single image then you would need to build a single image comprising everything **and** you may need (!?) to provide a mechanism to [run multiple processes](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) in the resulting container.